# I wanted to remove the GitHub login while accessing Netlify CMS for my gatsby blog but still getting login with GitHub button

Tags: reactjs, netlify, netlify-cms

I want to remove the Login with Gatsby option, I don't know why I'm getting it. I want to use the [image]Invite only Registration option which I've enabled.

here's the blog link[enter link description here](https://splendid-marzipan-18ef6c.netlify.app/)

I haven't installed OAuth provider as you can see in the screenshot.

Also, have enabled the invite only registrations,
[image]

but, still whenever I go to the /admin, I get the screen to log in with GitHub
[image]

I don't know why that's happening, here's my config.yml file

```
    backend:
  name: github
  repo: PavanSargar/test-blog
  commit_messages:
    create: "Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”"
    update: "Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”"
    delete: "Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”"
    uploadMedia: "[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”"
    deleteMedia: "[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”"

local_backend: true
media_folder: static/assets
public_folder: assets


slug:
  encoding: "ascii"
  clean_accents: true
  sanitize_replacement: "_"


collections:
  - name: posts
    label: Blog
    folder: src/blog
    create: true
    fields:
      - { name: path, label: Path }
      - { name: date, label: Date, widget: datetime}
      - { name: author, lable: "Author", widget: string, default: "sporttech"}
      - { name: title, label: Title, pattern: ['.{60,}', "Must have at least 60 characters"] }
      - { name: quote, label: Quote, required: false}
      - {label: "Featured Image", name: "thumbnail", widget: "image", required: true}
      - { name: body, label: Body, widget: markdown }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the [git-gateway](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/git-gateway-backend/#git-gateway-with-netlify) backend:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: main

media_folder: static/assets
public_folder: assets

[...]
```